# Выяснить источник запросов по JSON API

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Прошу помочь с решением вопроса или хотя бы направить нас. Уже потратили несколько дней, поддержка первого уровня не разбирает вопросы по API, все перепробовали и стоим в безвыходной ситуации.

Проблема: клиент обновляет товары в Мой склад (а именно меняет категорию). Тут же или спустя некоторое время товар возвращает в категорию, в которой был.

В аудите в логе мы видим вот такие записи:
"Изменен товар Электросамокат Ninebot by Segway Kickscooter ES1 по JSON API (версии 1.1) (95.213.136.74, GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.38.0 PHP/7.1.6)"
от логина главного админа.

Мы со своей стороны:
— поменяли пароль у этого логина. По идее этот же пароль является паролем к API и все должно было прикрепиться. Но нет — запросы продолжились.
— у нас 2 интеграции с этим паролем:
1) интеграция с сайтом (только запросы на получение данных, другое время выполнения, другой IP — то есть это точно не сайт)
2) интеграция с amocrm (пробовали отключать, проблема остается)

В итоге: пароль поменяли, все варианты откуда проблема у нас ушли, новый пароль больше никуда не вводили, а запросы на изменение товара остались. Нам нужно понять откуда они и отключить их.

P.S. Хочу обратить внимание (хотя это притянуто за уши), что IP с которого поступают запросы 95.213.136.74 из одной подсети с доменом moysklad.ru. Не похоже, чтобы этот IP принадлежал какому-то виртуальному хостингу. IP Мой склад и IP откуда идут запросы — оба принадлежат селектелу.
P.P.S. У клиента есть Касса от Мой склад.

Comment: Зайдя на 95.213.136.74, перебрасывает на https://www.amocrm.ru/. Похоже, дело в ней.

Comment: @TrufanovDmitrii большое спасибо за помощь! Не догадались перейти прямо по IP, но сейчас стало очевидным, что проблема в amo. При этом мы на пару дней отключали их виджет, проблема оставалась. Возможно часть операций они продолжали выполнять, будем разбираться дальше.